# An interest calculation task I'm working on doesn't output the proper results

Tags: c#, calculation

So I'm currently taking a C# fundamentals course as the entrance stage of a 6 month C# learning program. One of the tasks we have under the "Data Types and Variables" is an interest calculator.
The premise is such: You have a "deposit" that you write in the first line. The deposit has a 5% interest to it. The program needs to output the deposit's value for 3 years, for each year, all at once.
So 100.00, 105.00, 110.25, 115.76. The numbers after the decimal point need to be rounded to 2 digits, as well as "The rules of math for rounding apply here".

```
double deposit = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double interest = (deposit*5)/100;

            double yearOne = deposit + interest;
            double yearTwo = yearOne + interest;
            double yearThree = yearTwo + interest;

            string totalSums = ($"{yearOne:N2}\n{yearTwo:N2}\n{yearThree:N2}\n");
            
            Console.WriteLine( totalSums );
```

This is the code I've written so far. It SEEMS to work, but it's not as accepted.
If I put the deposit value as 100 (one of the examples), I get this output:
100
105.00
110.00
115.00

I've put the calculation for the interest percentage as `double interest = (deposit*5)/100`, which checks out if I use an external calculator to test it. But the program doesn't give the right output.
Say if I put 100.23 as the deposit input, I'll get: 105.24, 110.25, 115.26 when I should get 105.24, 110.50, 116.02. However, a round 100.00 doesn't even display the digits after the decimal point, just rounds them down to the whole number.

I thought the problem comes from using `double` and not `decimal` due to floating-point precision issues, so I changed everything to decimal. I still get this exact problem. Nothing changes.

I've had other issues that I at least have ideas on where I'm going wrong, but this one has been screwing with me since 3 days. So I resorted to some help here.

Why am I not getting the correct outputs ? Where is my problem coming from ? Is it the math ? Or logic ? Maybe I'm not using the correct method ? I'm at a loss... And the learning resources I've been given don't seem to help me with this issue, too. Like it's the ONLY task that the resources don't help with.

I've also seen other posts about compound interest, but they use arrays and other things that I'm not yet at the point of learning within the program. So code like that isn't gonna pass the automatic tester. I'm not asking for a complete code solving or "cheat" if you will; I just need some guidance on what my issue here is, because I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: Shouldn't the amount of interest added be determined by the *current* balance each year?  So you need to re-calculate the interest for each year?

Comment: Your `interest` is always `5`. So in yearOne, Two and Three you basically always do: 
`deposit +5`,  `yearOne + 5` and `yearTwo + 5 `. You shouldn't calculate the percentage over the `deposit` everytime. That will always result in `5`. After you've done that you once should calculate it over the next year: `interest = (yearOne*5)/100;`

Comment: Also, don't use `double` for currency values as it can't accurately represent `0.01`.

Comment: I am aware of that, but we haven't used decimal type yet.
I know that decimal should be used for anything that needs high precision past the decimal point, but simple results like these work with double and decimal, so in the scope of the task, it was all the same. When it comes to things specifically needing decimals, I'll definitely make sure to use that and not double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about compound interest, not simple interest. Therefore, you need to calculate the new interest every year.

```cs
double deposit = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double yearOne = deposit + (deposit * 5)/100;
double yearTwo = yearOne + (yearOne * 5)/100;
double yearThree = yearTwo + (yearTwo * 5)/100;

string totalSums = ($"{yearOne:N2}\n{yearTwo:N2}\n{yearThree:N2}\n");
            
Console.WriteLine( totalSums );
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just had that epiphany as I posted it and I did exactly what you did here just now. I heard hooves and thought zebras...
In my head, I felt like I had to DEFINE what the interest is first and then add it over each year, and completely glanced over the fact that my interest would be a flat 5% of the first deposit and not compounding over. I guess I just needed to articulate it and I figured it out basically as soon as I finished the post.
However, the tester gives me 80 points out of 100, so I'm still missing something...

Comment: You were thinking in terms of loops - which is a good concept to be grasping early in learning programming. This code can easily be refactored with loops to expand this logic to any number of years. [Learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you know about loops, you can create a loop over 3 years and update the amount in the account:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // set interest rate (fixed)
        decimal rate = 5m/100;
        // get deposit amount from user
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Initial Amount:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal amount = decimal.Parse(input);
        // loop over three years
        Console.WriteLine($"{"year"}\t{"amount"}");
        for (int year = 1; year <= 3; year++)
        {
            // calculate interest for the year based on 
            // current amount in the account
            decimal interest = rate * amount;
            // deposit interest in account
            amount += interest;
            Console.WriteLine($"{year}\t{amount:c2}");
        }
    }
}
```

with output

```text
Enter Initial Amount:
1000
year    amount
1       $1,050.00
2       $1,102.50
3       $1,157.63
```

Comment: UV for using `decimal` for financial calculations

Comment: As Bernard Borg said, I was thinking in terms of loops, but I haven't reached that point in the course, yet. So I can't use them, the tester won't accept it. But I was thinking that I could use the percentage formula I named "interest" and apply it over everything, but it didn't work. Lapse in logic. I'll take a look at this later, though! It would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to recalculate the interest amount each year.

```
        double deposit = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Use deposit to calculate interest
        double yearOneinterest = (deposit*5)/100;
        double yearOne = deposit + yearOneinterest;

        //Use yearOne amount to calculate interest
        double yearTwointerest = (yearOne*5)/100;
        double yearTwo = yearOne + yearTwointerest;

        //Use yearTwo amount to calculate interest
        double yearThreeinterest = (yearTwointerest*5)/100;
        double yearThree = yearTwo + yearThreeinterest;

        string totalSums = ($"{yearOne:N2}\n{yearTwo:N2}\n{yearThree:N2}\n");
        
        Console.WriteLine( totalSums );
```